# Ranks of a set of maximal invariant statistics

Tags: continuous-data, order-statistics, invariance

Let $\{\mathbf{x}_l\}_{l=1}^L$ be a set of i.i.d. (continuous) random vectors sharing the same density $p_X$. Let $\{Q_l\}_{l=1}^L$ be a set of (positive and continuous) random variables representing a set of maximal invariant statistics for $\{\mathbf{x}_l\}_{l=1}^L$ with respect to a group of transformations $\mathcal{G}$.

My question is: are the ranks $\{r_l\}_{l=1}^L$ of $\{Q_l\}_{l=1}^L$ themselves maximal invariant statistics for $\{\mathbf{x}_l\}_{l=1}^L$?

Thanks!